# why we don't create new iterator object in this case?

Tags: java, iterator, deque

this really confused me very much. Basically, I want to print the elements of two 1d-vector alternatively. And I found the solution attached below wrote by others.
In the main method, we call `zigzagIterator.next()` to print the number returned by `int num = iter.next()`

In the `next()` method, it seems that it created a new iter object every time when the `next()` method has been called. But when I debug, I found only two iterator object has been created. one is for a1, another is for a2. So that the cursor in each iterator object keeps its memory to iterate until the end.

It just doesn't make sense to me that `Iterator<Integer> iter = deque.pollLast()` has been called several times but only two objects created. Hope someone can help!! thanks a lot.

```
public class ZigzagIterator {
Deque<Iterator<Integer>> deque;

public ZigzagIterator(List<Integer> v1, List<Integer> v2) {
    deque = new LinkedList<Iterator<Integer>>();
    if(v1.size() != 0) deque.offerFirst(v1.iterator());
    if(v2.size() != 0) deque.offerFirst(v2.iterator());
}

public int next() {
    Iterator<Integer> iter = deque.pollLast();
    int num = iter.next();
    if(iter.hasNext()) deque.offerFirst(iter);
    return num;
}

public boolean hasNext() {
    return (deque.size() != 0);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<Integer> a1= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    a1.add(1);
    a1.add(2);
    a1.add(12);
    List<Integer> a2= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    a2.add(3);
    a2.add(4);
    a2.add(5);
    a2.add(6);
    ZigzagIterator zigzagIterator=new ZigzagIterator(a1, a2);
    while (zigzagIterator.hasNext()) 
    System.out.println(zigzagIterator.next());
}
}
```

Comment: I'm still confused what you are confused about.

Comment: the zigzagIterator.next() has been called 7 times in this code,  but only two iter object has been created by Iterator<Integer> iter = deque.pollLast() , only is for a1 anoter one is for a2

Comment: Because you did `deque.pollLast()` which removes the iterator instance from `deque`, and then `deque.offerFirst(iter)` which will put the *same* iterator instance at the front of the `deque`.

Comment: Why do you believe `pollLast()` *creates* an iterator? It doesn't. Only the `iterator()` method *creates* an iterator, which means the code creates two iterators in the constructor and adds them to the queue. The rest of the code uses those two iterators by taking them (poll) from the queue.

Comment: yes, u r correct! thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

Its because the object reference Remains the same, while the New objects created are being assigned to the 2 references (v1,v2) . thus last 2 object will get the 2 references resulting in 2 usable objects while others are garbage collectible

visit the **https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html**